# direction: rtl for scrollbar but text is being added to left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to make a simple calculator. Right now it just shows the math expression on the screen. On clicking the numbers , the text is added how I want. But on pressing any of the operators, the operator gets added to left side of number and then the next number is added left of the operator.

I want that the expression should come from left to right just as in real world, and in case of overflow, the scrollbar should start from right.

```js
var evt = document.querySelectorAll(".evt");
var screenText = document.getElementById("screentext");
var screenText2 = document.getElementById("screentext2");
var num = function(e) {
 screenText.innerHTML += e.currentTarget.textContent;
 screenText2.innerHTML += e.currentTarget.textContent;
}
var sign = function(e) {
 screenText.innerHTML += " " + e.currentTarget.textContent + " ";
 screenText2.innerHTML = "";
}

for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
 evt[i].addEventListener("click", num);
}
for(var i = 10 ; i < 14 ; i++) {
 evt[i].addEventListener("click", sign);
}
```

```css
#calcbody {
    width: 400px;
 height: 600px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}
#screen {
 width: 90%;
 height: 12%;
 border: 1px groove black;
 margin: 4% 5%;
 text-align: right;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
 direction: rtl;
}
#screen h1 {
 margin-top: 24px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 line-height: 22px;
}
#screen2 {
 width: 90%;
 height: 5%;
 border: 1px groove black;
 margin: 4% 5%;
}
#screentext2 {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 230px;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-top: 6px;
}
#current {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 130px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.flt {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 height: 13%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-left: 4%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 position: relative;
}
.flt2 {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 44%;
 height: 13%;
 margin-left: 4%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 position: relative;
}
.flt3 {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 92%;
 height: 13%;
 margin-left: 4%;
 position: relative;
}
.keys {
    text-align: center;
}
.back {
 background-color: red;
}
.evt:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: lime;
}
.evt:active {
 background-color: #00cc00;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="calcbody">
      <div id="screen"><h1 id="screentext"></h1></div>
      <div id="screen2"><p id="current">Current Number :</p><p id="screentext2"></p></div>
   <div id="num1" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">1</h1></div>
   <div id="num2" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">2</h1></div>
   <div id="num3" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">3</h1></div>
   <div id="num4" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">4</h1></div>
   <div id="num5" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">5</h1></div>
   <div id="num6" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">6</h1></div>
   <div id="num7" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">7</h1></div>
   <div id="num8" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">8</h1></div>
   <div id="num9" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">9</h1></div>
   <div id="num0" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">0</h1></div>
   <div id="plus" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">+</h1></div>
   <div id="minus" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">-</h1></div>
   <div id="multiply" class="flt2 evt"><h1 class="keys">*</h1></div>
   <div id="divide" class="flt2 evt"><h1 class="keys">/</h1></div>
   <div id="equal" class="flt3 evt"><h1 class="keys">=</h1></div>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: But that's not how `rtl` text works. If I wrote `101 +` in `ltr` then it is correct to be `+ 101` in `rtl` as the order is correctly reversed. - I don't think `rtl` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `rtl` and added `screenText.parentElement.scrollLeft = screenText.parentElement.scrollWidth;` to have the scroll start from right

```js
var evt = document.querySelectorAll(".evt");
var screenText = document.getElementById("screentext");
var screenText2 = document.getElementById("screentext2");

for(var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
  evt[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    screenText.innerHTML += e.currentTarget.textContent;
    screenText2.innerHTML += e.currentTarget.textContent;
    screenText.parentElement.scrollLeft = screenText.parentElement.scrollWidth;
  });
}
for(var i = 10 ; i < 14 ; i++) {
  evt[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    screenText.innerHTML += " " + e.currentTarget.textContent + " ";
    screenText2.innerHTML = "";
    screenText.parentElement.scrollLeft = screenText.parentElement.scrollWidth;
  });
}
```

```css
#calcbody {
    width: 400px;
 height: 600px;
 border: 2px solid black;
}
#screen {
 width: 90%;
 height: 12%;
 border: 1px groove black;
 margin: 4% 5%;
 text-align: right;
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
#screen h1 {
 margin-top: 24px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 line-height: 22px;
}
#screen2 {
 width: 90%;
 height: 5%;
 border: 1px groove black;
 margin: 4% 5%;
}
#screentext2 {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 230px;
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-top: 6px;
}
#current {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 130px;
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 2px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.flt {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 height: 13%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-left: 4%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 position: relative;
}
.flt2 {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 44%;
 height: 13%;
 margin-left: 4%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
 position: relative;
}
.flt3 {
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid black;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 92%;
 height: 13%;
 margin-left: 4%;
 position: relative;
}
.keys {
    text-align: center;
}
.back {
 background-color: red;
}
.evt:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: lime;
}
.evt:active {
 background-color: #00cc00;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="calcbody">
      <div id="screen"><h1 id="screentext"></h1></div>
      <div id="screen2"><p id="current">Current Number :</p><p id="screentext2"></p></div>
   <div id="num1" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">1</h1></div>
   <div id="num2" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">2</h1></div>
   <div id="num3" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">3</h1></div>
   <div id="num4" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">4</h1></div>
   <div id="num5" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">5</h1></div>
   <div id="num6" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">6</h1></div>
   <div id="num7" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">7</h1></div>
   <div id="num8" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">8</h1></div>
   <div id="num9" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">9</h1></div>
   <div id="num0" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">0</h1></div>
   <div id="plus" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">+</h1></div>
   <div id="minus" class="flt evt"><h1 class="keys">-</h1></div>
   <div id="multiply" class="flt2 evt"><h1 class="keys">*</h1></div>
   <div id="divide" class="flt2 evt"><h1 class="keys">/</h1></div>
   <div id="equal" class="flt3 evt"><h1 class="keys">=</h1></div>
  </div>
 </body>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i need, but can u explain your solution, i dont understand - screenText.parentElement.scrollLeft = screenText.parentElement.scrollWidth;

Comment: @DhruvChadha: The `screenText` is the element with the text, and its parent, `screenText.parentElement`, is the element having the scroll, so that code keep the scroll at its right side.

Comment: 1) Just to clarify, screenText.parentElement.scrollWidth is actually much greater than we actually want to scroll, but we want the scrollbar to extreme right and so just to be safe, we used scrollWidth? 2) Also, am i right in saying that the same can be achived by using screenText.parentElement.scrollLeft += 100; each time function is called? (100 is somewhat upperlimit of any additional character added)
 @LGSon

Comment: @DhruvChadha 1: Correct, using `scrollWidth` ensure that no matter how many characters is added/pasted/etc., it will always be far left enough, **but** never more than required ..2: Yes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#screentext {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

Your ltr definition is on the #screen div, and not in the h1 (#scrrentext).

Comment: This just _undo_ the `rtl`, better to just remove it on `#screen`

Answer (score 0):

Remove that **rtl** and add **ltr**, as below.

```
#screen {
width: 90%;
height: 12%;
border: 1px groove black;
margin: 4% 5%;
text-align: right;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
direction: ltr;
}
```

Comment: That's true, even if you won't add it will work. But just remove your direction rtl from that, as ltr is default, so it's upto you.